# How can i get draggable ui in droppable over event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to get draggable ui in droppable over event, but every time im getting `undefined` in the console. So when I drag my ui draggable to a new div I wanna get the draggable ui in my over event of droppable. Is this possible?

Here is a piece of my code:

```
$(".droppable").droppable({
        over: function(event, ui){
            console.log("ui", ui);
        }
});
```

[Console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkVta.png)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you got undefined, but here is a working example:

```js
$( "#draggable" ).draggable();
$( "#droppable" ).droppable({
  drop: function() {
    alert( "dropped" );
  },
  over: function(event, ui) {
    console.log(ui)
  }
});
```

```css
#draggable {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #ccc;
  }
  #droppable {
    position: absolute;
    left: 250px;
    top: 0;
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
    background: #999;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="droppable">Drop here</div>
<div id="draggable">Drag me</div>
```

Comment: When i use `ui.draggable.appendTo(this)` im getting my element in console but when i click on the element in console I am not getting it in html it's like removed.

Comment: What do you mean "click on the element in the console" ?

Comment: I have posted a picture of it what I mean, when i click on this `[0]` element.